# Angular2 Universal, where and how to learn?

Tags: angular, angular2-universal

Angular2 Universal seems to me some kind of black magic, I can't find where I can learn this language from the beginning, neither in the official web site have an introduction to the language, only an documentation. Where I can learn this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even thought there are [some](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-CD_5YhJTA) really good video tutorials but I prefer [this](https://www.ng-book.com/2/) book which is the only complete reference that I found for Angular2 apart from the documentation. Its simple with practical projects and also covers all topics in a systematic and simple manner.

Answer (score 0):

[This is where I started](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

Pretty steep learning curve. I recommend you go through codecademy's (quick) walkthrough Angular.js beforehand -- if you ain't familiar with Angular.js, that is.

Once you're done with the quickstart, [do try the tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/).

Comment: I don't see where these sites talk about Angular2 Universal. They only teach about Angular2. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I'll make sure I read questions twice when it's past midnight. Sorry about that mate.